# Re sizing Window to Smaller Screen Without Losing Elements

Tags: wpf, window, frame, scrollviewer

[Window with frame containing main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4kUn.jpg)

As you can see, (if the image loads correctly) when I run the program from my lap top I cannot see the whole screen, nor can I scroll to see the rest of the elements contained by the frame. I have tried to add a scrollviewer to contain the frame but the scroll bar does nothing and the elements of the canvas are relocated or disappear. Am I including the correct code to fit the window to the screen size? Should I have to use a scrollviewer to see the whole window or at least the elements in the frame's page?

```
    Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
    Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" 
    Loaded="Window_Load" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Comment: What kind of panels are your controls in? And what kind of properties are set? That determines how WPF decides to layout and size the controls. ScrollViewers will only work if you set a Height/Width on them, otherwise depending on their parent panel they will probably grow to allow whatever size the contents want.

Comment: I am using canvas for the containers. The pages contain a canvas that contains list boxes, text boxes and richtextboxes.

Comment: That's your problem then.. `Canvas` requires you specify the position of every child element, and it doesn't scale it at all. You could wrap your Canvas in a ScrollViewer, but you'd have to set the Height/Width of both the ScrollViewer and the Canvas. A better solution would be to use a different Layout Control to display your items to allow for a more dynamic display. If you're new to WPF's layout controls, I'd recommend this post : [WPF Layouts - A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start)

Comment: I think I use the canvas because it's easy and I'm lazy. So, under the window, I should use a grid, and the grid should be wrapped in a ScrollViewer? Or just the frame? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want your application to dynamically size based on window size? It usually looks a bit nicer, and you can always give a MinSize to enforce a minimum size. ScrollViewer should wrap the Panel containing all your controls, and you need to ensure the ScrollViewer height/width is whatever the screen size is. You could bind that, or you could place it in a DockPanel with DockPanel.Dock=Fill, since DockPanel resizes it's children to fit available size. Whatever panel you have wrapping your controls needs to be one that can grow to fill whatever space is needed, such as StackPanel, Grid, etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScrollViewer` in a window as following:

```
 <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualHeight,Mode=OneWay}">
    <canvas>
............
</ScrollViewer>
```

**A Sample Output:** (Bind the `MaxWidth` of `Scrollviewer` also if there is problem with `width` too)

[image: scrollviewer]

Answer (score 0):

> Re sizing Window to Smaller Screen Without Losing Elements

I think I speak for many by saying we strongly recommend moving away from a `Canvas` to perform your layout.  `Canvas` can be easy to lean as you mentioned in the comments as it is quite close to the way a simple form based windows app is created.

The WPF layout panels are specifically designed for what you are asking for.

A possible structure is this

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Location"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Product Line"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Search"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <StackPanel>
               ...
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```